# Cortana VCD Storage Location

Tags: cortana

I've been actively creating, debugging, and installing VCD files with our application and I've been looking for a way to remove VCD files from the command definition set.

Does anyone know how to do this, even if it is a hack (such as removing the xml file that is registered)?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there isn't a way to remove a registered VCD explicitly, currently you need to remove your app, and then an attempt to trigger any of the voice commands the VCD registers will detect the missing app and remove the VCD.

However, this functionality isn't super-robust, and is set to be improved over time to become more reliable. (For instance, right now, two apps can install the same VCD and cause issues that are difficult to clean up).

Comment: Thanks for the response - while this is technically the API supported method, I am still trying to understand where the VCD is registered within the operating system.  Is it stored inside of the application and it creates a reference so some registry key in Windows?  Does it store the XML in some type of database repository?  I had an issue in which the uninstall of the application did not remove the VCD until I rebooted the computer...I'd like to avoid escalations of this manner when the app is released to end-users...has there been any disclosure on how this mechanism works?

Comment: No, we haven't documented how Cortana stores VCDs internally, and I don't know of plans to do so. Currently, having the VCD not get removed on app uninstall, and having it get cleaned up at a later point is by design, although it is a design that's destined to change down the line (I just don't have a timeframe to share.)

Comment: @AndrewPilley-MSFT Is there a way to delete all app VCDs with something like a 'cortana-reset'? It would be handy since I uninstalled all apps and Cortana keeps crashing with certain keywords to a point where I can't continue development on this voice recognition project even after several days/reboots.

Comment: There's no way to explicitly reset Cortana's registered VCDs. Ensure you've upgraded to the november release (1511). If you uninstall the app(s) that have registered commands, attempting to use that command will cause it to be unregistered (however, this takes a few minutes before it will work, as it takes a short period for an app to actually get removed when you uninstall it). An alternative would be to install a blank VCD from that same app that doesn't register any commands, which would override any existing VCDs.

Comment: sure would be nice to get a look at them and make sure you weren't trying to install a command that was already in place...   maybe part of your functionality should include that...  voice command config files can be found here %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_{...}\LocalState\

Comment: it also appears that you can find the config files for your app in the grammars folder--you can match it to your app if you are unsure by looking at the app Name (identity) and comparing it to the identity in your manifest...  i haven't tried but i would bet deleting all references to these config files would erase your voice command definitions...     of course andy could verify that for us, right andy?